# What is a Web Framework?

Tags: node.js, express, web, frameworks

can somebody explain me, what a **Web Framework** is? In a tutorial I am supposed to use **express** (node.js), which is a web framework. But before I was just using PHP in order to responde to HTTP-GET/-POST requests. So why do I need express for?

To be more precise. What does such a Web Framework include? Before I was able to have a MySQL-Database and connected to it using PHP. This way I could store new data or send data to the user. How the Web Framework facilitates this process?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_framework

Comment: A web framework is what makes it easier to respond to HTTP GETs and POSTs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express is a framework that allows you to interact easily with HTTP. It provides several tools to start a web application very easy. Take into account that Node.js is not precisely intended for web applications, but for Server-side applications. That means that you can do everything from a console app to a web app by using Node. Express encapsulates everything that you need to make a web application so you can start doing what you used to do in PHP straight away.

A web framework is just a framework that helps you making things for the web.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response.

Comment: So, a web framework is facilitates the response to the request. In this case node.js replaces PHP. I read that this way, the developer can keep using JavaScript instead of  PHP. I think I slowly understand.